# Is there any punishment mentioned in Dharmashastras for the vilification of Vedas?

Tags: vedas, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, smriti, parashara-smriti

I was wondering whether criticizing the Vedas is a condemnable offence. In other religions, usually condemning the scripture can have a severe consequence. What about Hinduism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a punishment. TL;DR -- Criticizing the Vedas is an act of a Pisaca, a mortal sin, and causes loss of caste.

Dharmasutra/Dharmashastra Evidence:

> atha patanīyāni || 7 || 
> 7. Now [follows the enumeration of] the **actions which cause loss of caste**
> [Pataniya].
>
> steyam ābhiśastyaṃ puruṣa vadho brahma ujjhaṃ garbha śātanam mātuḥ
> pitur iti yoni saṃbandhe saha-apatye strī gamanaṃ surā pānam asaṃyoga
> saṃyogaḥ || 8 || 
> 8. [These are] (a) stealing [gold], (b) crimes whereby one becomes an
> Abhiśasta, (c) homicide, **(d) neglect of the Vedas**, (e) causing abortion, (f)
> incestuous connection with maternal or paternal uncles or aunts, (g) and
> with the offspring of such persons (cousins), (h) alcoholism, and (i)
> socializing with persons the interaction with whom is forbidden.
>
> Apastamba Sutra 1.7.21

By Apastamba Sutra, neglect of the Vedas (which occurs with criticism) causes loss of caste.

> 4.163. Let him **avoid** atheism, **cavilling at the Vedas**, contempt of the gods, hatred, want of modesty, pride, anger, and harshness
>
> 11.56. Forgetting the Veda, **reviling the Vedas**, giving false evidence, slaying a friend, eating forbidden food, or (swallowing substances) unfit for food, **are** six (offences) **equal to drinking Sura**.
>
> Manu Smriti

Manu Smriti equals the punishment of criticizing the Vedas to the punishment of drinking Sura. Now, let's see what happens when you drink Sura.

> 9.237. For violating a Guru’s bed, (the mark of) a female part shall be (impressed on the forehead with a hot iron); **for drinking (the spirituous liquor called) Sura, the sign of a tavern**; for stealing (the gold of a Brahmana), a dog’s foot; for murdering a Brahmana, a headless corpse.
>
> 11.54. Killing a Brahmana, **drinking (the spirituous liquor called) Sura**, stealing (the gold of a Brahmana), adultery with a Guru’s wife, and associating with such (offenders), **they declare (to be) mortal sins (mahapataka)**.
>
> 11.95. **Sura, (all other) intoxicating drinks** and decoctions and flesh **are the food of the Yakshas, Rakshasas, and Pisakas**; a Brahmana who eats (the remnants of) the offerings consecrated to the gods, must not partake of such (substances).
>
> 11.97. When the Brahman (the Veda) which dwells in his body is (even) once (only) deluged with spirituous liquor, **his Brahmanhood forsakes him and he becomes a Sudra**.
>
> Manu Smriti

The last verse agrees with Apastamba in that criticizing the Vedas causes loss of caste. However, Manu Smriti expands by saying that it is a mortal sin and that criticizing the Vedas is an act of a Pisaca. This agrees with Sanantan Darshan's answer as well.

Answer (score 9):

According to Skanda Purana V.ii.68.24-33 , one who speaks wrong about vedas and gods becomes pishacha.

> Those who commit breach of trust, those who have sex with other men’s wives and those **who speak ill of the Vedas, attain the state of Piśāca. Men who always decry the Purāṇas and Dharmaśāstras and who calumniate others become Piśācas.**

Other scriptures prescribes hell for these people.

> A rejector of proofs, a **slanderer** of the interpretation of the **Vedic scriptures**, a transgressor urged by lust and covetousness, **that fool goeth to hell.”**

> **Vana Parva Section III**

> Brahma Purana 106.135 “There is a hell named Atratistha. It contains putrescent urine and faeces. **Those who censure Smrtis and the Vedas** fall into it with faces downwards.”

> Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Krishna Janma Khanda 40.116-141 “…A sinner who **slanders** Brahma, the creator of the world, the goddess Durga who is the best of female deities, Laksmi, Saraswati, Sita, Tulsi, Ganga, **the Vedas,** the mother of the Vedas, a vow, devotion, mystic formula pertaining to worship of the spiritual guide who gives formula **will dwell in the hell called the ‘Blind well’** for half the period of the longevity allotted to Brahma, where bitten by snakes he will scream dreadfully.